# hide navigation bar programmatically while application running

Tags: navigationbar, android

I am developing an android game with webview layout. I would like to hide the navigation bar while the user is playing the game. I have found some solutions but when I touch the screen the navigation bar shows up.

What am I doing wrong? Here is my non-working solution:

```
 int mUIFlag = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(mUIFlag);
```

Comment: take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html to make changes again when the navigation bar is visible

Comment: thanks for answer  @user3487063. I tried your solitions and when visibiltiy change also navigation bar is hiding. But when i touch screen navigations bar is showing up again. I think i need touch listener. in your solitions when visibility change one time your code enter the cycle. becuse visibility change listener is changing visibility with some UI flags. am i false ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to make use of following piece of code to reset the flags again :

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
        (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
        // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
           decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(mUIFlag);
        } else {
            // TODO: The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired
            // adjustments to your UI, such as hiding the action bar or
            // other navigational controls.
        }
    }
});
```

also, read through [this](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html) page to know how to handle your scenario

Comment: in your solitions when visibility change one time your code enter the cycle. becuse visibility change listener is changing visibility with some UI flags. am i false ?

Comment: please see my edited answer, you need to reset flags when navigation bar is visible.